How to add Azure speech to text & Azure translator services behind Azure APIM?
We are using Azure cognitive services for my application we are directly calling those endpoint keys to access but how to put behind Azure APIM is big question for me.
I am trying to add them but I was not able to test those services for speech to text service I have added a web socket and translate service added https endpoint but I didn't seen any api calls in Azure APIM management service & unable to test as well.

Please add some screenshots to your question to make it clear how exactly you're configuring your API Management service and any details of the errors.

@vijay kumar Please read  How to Ask, along with how to create a  minimal reproducible example.
